# Web Scraping returns None

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the price of a list of monitors from Amazon, using request and bs4 -

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',}

res = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?i=specialty-aps&bbn=16225007011&rh=n%3A16225007011%2Cn%3A1292115011&ref=nav_em__nav_desktop_sa_intl_monitors_0_2_6_8", headers=headers)

print(res)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

price=soup.find_all(class_="a-price-whole")

print(price.text)
```

I don't understand why it returns None - I'm basically following a video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY&t=467s&ab_channel=DevEd, and on their side it returns the text - can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably received captcha page. Try to add `"Accept-Language"` HTTP header:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
}

res = requests.get(
    "https://www.amazon.com/s?i=specialty-aps&bbn=16225007011&rh=n%3A16225007011%2Cn%3A1292115011&ref=nav_em__nav_desktop_sa_intl_monitors_0_2_6_8",
    headers=headers,
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
prices = soup.find_all(class_="a-price-whole")
for price in prices:
    print(
        price.find_previous("h2").text[:30] + "...",
        price.text + price.find_next(class_="a-price-fraction").text,
    )
```

Prints:

```
Sceptre IPS 27-Inch Business C... 159.17
EVICIV 12.3’’ Raspberry Pi Tou... 199.99
Portable Monitor, 17.3'' IPS H... 349.99
Acer R240HY bidx 23.8-Inch IPS... 129.99
Dell SE2419Hx 24" IPS Full HD ... 169.95
HP Pavilion 22cwa 21.5-Inch Fu... 139.99
Sceptre E248W-19203R 24" Ultra... 127.98
LG 27GL83A-B 27 Inch Ultragear... 379.99
LG 24M47VQ 24-Inch LED-lit Mon... 99.99
LG 27UN850-W 27 Inch Ultrafine... 404.14
Sceptre IPS 24-Inch Business C... 142.17
Planar PXN2400 Full HD Thin Pr... 139.00
Sceptre IPS 24-Inch Business C... 142.17
Portable Triple Screen Laptop ... 419.99
ASUS ZenScreen 15.6" 1080P Por... 232.52
HP M27ha FHD Monitor - Full HD... 199.99
ASUS 24" 1080P Gaming Monitor ... 189.99
Dell P2419H 24 Inch LED-Backli... 187.99
LG 32QN600-B 32-Inch QHD (2560... 249.99
LG 29WN600-W 29" 21:9 UltraWid... 226.99
Acer Nitro XV272U Pbmiiprzx 27... 299.99
AOC C24G1 24" Curved Frameless... 186.99
Samsung CF390 Series 27 inch F... 199.00
ASUS VY279HE 27” Eye Care Moni... 219.00
SAMSUNG LC24F396FHNXZA 23.5" F... 149.99
Sceptre E275W-19203R 27" Ultra... 169.97
ASUS VG245H 24 inchFull HD 108... 164.95
PEPPER JOBS 15.6" USB-C Portab... 199.99
13.3 inch Portable Monitor,KEN... 96.99
Eyoyo Small Monitor 8 inch Min... 76.98
```